# Is Wildcard Functionality Possible in Firestore Queries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm trying to decide how to model data in firestore.

Basically, it's for an app that lists happy hours and other specials that restaurants have. Each restaurant/bar could have multiple specials and happy hours depending on the day of the week.

This is a very simplified example of how I was *hoping* to model the data:

```
name: "Margaritaville",
geo: {
  latitude: 42,
  longitude: -105
},
offers {
  0: {Type: Happy Hours, Time: 3p-6p, Mon: 1, Tue: 1, Wed: 1, Thu: 1, Fri: 0, Sat: 0, Sun: 0 },
  1: {Type: Happy Hours, Time: 2p-5p, Mon: 0, Tue: 0, Wed: 0, Thu: 0, Fri: 1, Sat: 1, Sun: 0},
  2: {Type: Happy Hours, Time: All Day, Mon: 0, Tue: 0, Wed: 0, Thu: 0, Fri: 0, Sat: 0, Sun: 1},
  3: {Type: Brunch Special, Time: 11a-2p, Mon: 0, Tue: 0, Wed: 0, Thu: 0, Fri: 0, Sat: 0, Sun: 1}
},
etc: "foo",
etc: "bar"
```

I WANTED to store all the offers data as a nested object inside each business document rather than as a separate collection, as most of the queries will require most of this information along with the lat/long, photos, name, etc. But...

I ultimately want to be able to do query filters by day of the week (Mon, Tue, etc) and offer times and offer types (Happy Hours, Brunch) and distance from user, etc. The way the info is modeled now however, the "offers" that are created inside each document, are ordered (0, 1, 2 etc), so if I wanted to perform a query of all restaurants within 10 miles that have happy hour specials on Monday, for example, I was hoping to do something like this:

```
db.collection("restaurants").where("offers.WILDCARD.days.Mon", "==", 1)
```

Note, the "WILDCARD" above. Is there any way to make this work, or do I have to move offers to a separate collection or subcollection? I've been trying to wrap my head around de-normalization, I've only ever worked with SQL databases, so I'm open to advice with regard to how I should be thinking about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support any wildcards in queries.  Furthermore, if your "offers" field is an array, you won't be able to query any of its nested object contents.

What you should do instead is break out "offers" into a subcollection, with each of its elements being a new document in that subcollection.  You can query the subcollection for matches against the document properties.  If you find a match, then you can do a second `get()` to find the parent document if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to create an "offers" subcollection for each restaurant, and with the ability to do [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), I think I should be set.